# Catkin-izing OpenCV-based package

Tags: opencv, catkin, opencv2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I converted my package that relies on OpenCV to catkin but I am getting lots of OpenCV errors. Is there somewhere that documents the required OpenCV changes to port to the new version?

catkin_make is outputting [these errors](https://gist.github.com/4255450).

This is my [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/davetcoleman/clam_catkin/blob/master/src/clam_vision/CMakeLists.txt) and this is the [Github package repo](https://github.com/davetcoleman/clam_catkin/tree/master/src/clam_vision).

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50143/catkin-izing-opencv-based-package/) by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1396 on 2012-12-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need opencv and all the other elements in your CATKIN_DEPENDS element also in your find_package call.  CATKIN_DEPENDS only exposes those elements to your downstream packages, not your own package.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2012-12-12**:
perfect, thanks! each dependency sure requires a lot of duplication in the package.xml and CMakeLists.txt